# No name 'fft' in module 'scipy'

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I tried to import FFT from SciPy and got "No name 'fft' in module 'scipy' ". Last time I checked, Scipy did have these modules, so I don't know why I'm getting this error.
[image]

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  The `scipy.fft` module--a replacement for `scipy.fftpack`--was added in SciPy 1.4.0.

Answer (score 4):

As provided in this [issue](https://github.com/davidpraise45/Audio-Signal-Processing/issues/1)

The solution should be:

```py
from scipy.fftpack import fft
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html) fftpack is deprecated. Nevertheless, I get the same error with the current version (1.7.3) when importing scipy.fft when analyzing the code with pylint.

The problem seems to be these two lines at the end of scipy's `__init__.py`
:

```
    # This makes "from scipy import fft" return scipy.fft, not np.fft
    del fft
```